# html5 Loading video once to play in different divs

Tags: jquery, html, video

I'd like to know what's the best way to load the same html5 video into two different divs (say, a 'thumbnail' and a full width containers) without straining the browser, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just giving the user the option of two different sizes and only expect the user to actually play one of the them, then you probably don't need to do anything if you are using video streaming and the regular HTML5 video tag or a HTML5 based video player.

When the user hits play, the video will be streamed in whichever div they choose. Before this the impact will be minimal as only a small part of the video will be downloaded.

If you are doing something more complex then it will depend on the exact scenario - for example if you wanted to reduce bandwidth by storing the video when it is played in one window so it can be played in the other later, you are trading off storage against bandwidth, and videos can eat up a lot of storage.

Also, if the case is as you describe with one thumbnail size video and one full width, the streamed video may be different files anyway - the thumbnail size div may not need as high quality video streamed to it to display the video.

If you want to display many thumbnails on a single page, say with a grid of different videos, you may find the most efficient way to do this is to combine the videos into a single stream on the server side. This is because playing multiple videos simultaneously can quickly overcome a devices processing capability, especially when the device has some sort of dedicated video HW or HW accelerated playback capability.